# Node/Socket IO Multiple Players

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using node & socketi IO to create a simple multiplayer game. When a new client joins, I create a new HTML element with an ID which is each clients socket.id.

The clients are mobile devices, and when they move, I'm sending the 'deviceorientation' values, hoping to give each client control over one of the HTML elements. I'm doing something incorrectly though, which I can't quite figure out, as all that happens is all the clients fight for control over the newest HTML element, rather than having control over the HTML element with their own socket id.

On the server:

```
servio.on('connection', function (socket) {

    servio.sockets.emit('newplayer',socket.id);

    socket.on('move', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('clientmove', data);
        console.log(data.myid);
    });

});
```

On the client:

```
iosocket.on('newplayer', function(data) {
            myid    =   data;
            $('body').append('<div class="dot _jsDot" id="'+myid+'"></div>');
        });

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);

        function handleOrientation(event) {
            var absolute = event.absolute;
            var alpha    = event.alpha;
            var beta     = event.beta;
            var gamma    = event.gamma;

            vals = {
                betaVal     : beta,
                gammaVal    : gamma,
                myid        : myid
            }

            iosocket.emit('move', vals);
        }

        iosocket.on('clientmove', function(data) {

            var x = Math.round(data.gammaVal)*3;
            var y = Math.round(data.betaVal)*3;

            $('#'+data.myid+'').css({'left':x + $(window).outerWidth()/2});
            $('#'+data.myid+'').css({'top':y + $(window).outerHeight()/2});

        });
```

I'm hoping I'm overlooking something small rather than some fundamental mess up. If anyone more experienced with node & socket io can offer some advice, that would be great.

Comment: If you look at the source using the Dev tools in Chrome/Firefox (right click -> inspect element), do the elements have the correct IDs or do they all have id="undefined" or something like that? Could be something that simple.

Comment: Is myid a global variable? Because it looks like your overwriting the clients id whenever a new client is connected

Answer (score 0):

You're updating everyone's `myid` to the new player's id. I suggest you differentiate between the two.

on the server do something like:

```
everyone.push(socket.id); // global array of all player ids
socket.emit('init',[socket.id,everyone]);
servio.sockets.emit('newplayer',socket.id);
```

on the client do something like:

```
socket.on('newplayer', function(data) {
    myid = data.id;
    create_div_with(data.id);
    create_everyone_else(data.everyone);
});
socket.on('newplayer', function(id) {
    create_div_with(id);
});
```